# HTML canvas: drawing separated circles

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I wanted to draw some circles on the canvas with the following layout: A circle right in the centre of the canvas and four circles at the mid points of the four edges of the canvas. I've put up my code here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkryder/s4dt9fzt/). The circles are rendered, however there are multiple filled paths between them too, resulting in an amalgamated mess.

I'm drawing all the circles by using

```
ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
```

How do I remove them ?

EDIT: working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkryder/s4dt9fzt/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably wanting to fill after each arc.

Something like this should work

```
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
ctx.fill();
for(var i = 0; i < points.length; i++){
    var _ = points[i];

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(_.x, _.y, 25, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put `closePath` after each circular-arc so that the circles are not connected:

```
ctx.arc(points[i].x, points[i].y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);

ctx.closePath();
```